# Plotly.js staticPlot vs normal render quality

Tags: javascript, svg, plotly, plotly.js

I'm using Plotly.js to render some simple charts, but I'm having an issue on the final look of the result.

When I use the `staticPlot: true` configuration. It renders as I want, with a nice antialias like this:

[image: example rendered chart]

But when I do change the `staticPlot` to `false` because I need the tooltips on values, basically. I have a much worse quality output.

[image: example rendered chart without staticplot turned on]

Is there any way to force the same rendering method as in static plot? I figure this is because performance improvements when the chart is more dynamic, but I don't need any advanced interactions, just tooltips. I've already tried forcing `shape-rendering` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering)) on `path` tags of the SVG, which seems to work when I apply it to the staticPlot to make it `optimizeSpeed` but in the opposite way, which is what I need. Doesn't work.